# Loop over variable names in R

Tags: r

I have a list of variable names and I want to perform some operation on the corresponding variable, for instance to check what class the variable is. I could for instance try:

```
for(i in c('var1', 'var2', 'var3')) {
    varname <- paste('df', i, sep = '')
    print(class(varname))
}
```

Obviously this does not work because varname is a string. One suggestion would be to use `print(class(get(varname)))`, but that does not work. Another suggestion would be `print(class(df[i]))` but then the class is data.frame which is not what I want. This seems to be a very simple problem but as a novice with R I have not found a solution.

Comment: Are you looking for the column values?  You can just do `df[[i]]` (double brackets).

Comment: As I said, very simple problem and a very simple solution, thank you Rich!

Comment: SO Docs: [R - Basic Subsetting](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/1686/basic-subsetting#t=201611021920169597389).